# openDatabase error in mac safari

Tags: javascript, macos, sqlite, safari, web-sql

When try to save/load from websqlite using "window.openDatabase(...)" in mac safari, sometimes fails with the following exception:

```
sqlite cannot open database file
```

Then the websql can no-longer use unless reload the page.

Does anybody know how it can be solved? THX.

p.s. It`s on desktop mac safari, not ios safari or the issue "less or more data stored more than 5MB question".

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe that Safari doesn't seem to be able to garbage collect openDatabase connections, are you making a lot of openDatabase calls? perhaps one per row? to avoid this make sure you cache and reuse your database handles.

For further information, see this task which has a good discussion.

https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/1068